# How can i add dynamic data inside flag series in highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am getting data in this code my chart is running,i added flags for MAX value and Min Value in X-axis,now i want to display rating inside flag.but here my catagories data is come but rating is not come on flag.here my data and rating is dynamically data not static. I Have already tried on stack overflow suggestion,as well as by including  highstock.js and highcharts.js file but it still not working. Please give me proper solution for column chart.

```
  $(document). ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 50
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Top 15 Projects Facilities Rating',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Facilities Rating'
                },
               stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            plotOptions:{
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color:'white'
                }
            }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name:'RATING',
                data:[],
                id:'dataseries'
           },
    {      
    type: 'flags',
    onSeries: 'dataseries',
    data: [{
        x: 0,
        text: 'Minimum Facilites Rating',
        title: 'Min'
    }, {
        x: 15,
        text: 'Maximum Facilites Rating',
        title: 'max'
    }],
    width: 30,
    showInLegend: false
    }]
        }

        $.getJSON("bargraph_data.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
           // options.series.splice(0,0, json[1]);
            options.series[0].data = json[1]['data'];

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
```

u can check also in [link]http://jsfiddle.net/sunitasingh/n3U77/3/
please give me solution for how can i add y-value to the flag series point dynamic not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting flags by default series.. check this line:

```
options.series[0] = json[1];
```

It will replace flags with new series. I guess you need to prepend options, like this:

```
options.series.splice(0, 0, json[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Fus you suggestion is helpful but one more query for the same. data is undefined in the series 2 and flag is showing on bottom of the chart i required top of the chart on up side. This is  Column chart with data from MySQL using Highcharts

Comment: Why data is undefined in series 2? If series doesn't exists, or Id for series doesn't match (from here: `onSeries: 'dataseries'`) then flags will be displayed on a xAxis.

Comment: Fus .i have added this code inside series ..still it shows undefined..but inside series2 my data is dynamic.so tell me how it is called inside data[],/--code    series: [{
              data: [],
            id: 'dataseries',
            
        type: 'flags',
        onSeries: 'dataseries', // and one thing i want to show min and max flag on top of the bar.but it shows bottom of the bar.here i am using verticalAlign: 'top',

Comment: What code? You should add `id: 'dataseries'` for data series, not for a flags.. What show as undefined? Where did you get `verticalAlign` for flags..? There's no such option.

Comment: Fus Still now not working inside dataseries.give me example on my code.i want when mouse is hover on min or max ..then it shows with project name:with rating which comes from db.but here on mouse hover it only shows project name:undefined.. please see on this link  http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2BGSK/   here how the flag is shows on top of the graph ...but in mycase it shows bottom of the graph.thats i want.so please suggest me

Comment: Create example with issue, otherwise I wouldn't be able to find solution. Your example works fine, then probably you have something wrong with data.

Comment: Fus Please check my top code.i have already edit this.still i am not found proper graph as per my required.otherwise send me your id where can i discussed.

Comment: You have changed code.. with actual code, just add data to the first series. See: http://jsfiddle.net/8jmV6/4/

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Fus .but inside flag, when i mouse over on max or min.that time it shows undefined.i want whatever comes in rating that also shows inside flag.is it possible?pls check [link] http://jsfiddle.net/8jmV6/4/.but my data is comes from another page such bargraph_data.php. so give me solution how can call this json value inside flag.

Comment: Fus Thank you so much.i am very glad for you.to solve my query..now i update my code ..at the place of y-value to the flag series point,u have already added static variable but i want to add dynamic data.so how can i add dynamic data in y-value to the flag series.

Comment: Fus .please give me suggestion of my prev comment

Comment: You need to get value from series data, and then update flags to that values? Simply use `point.update()`.

Comment: Fus Thank you for your response. One thing tell me.in which line i will add ** point.update() **

Comment: Fus I have a another problem in Highcharts.Can u suggest me this question's answer [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287444/generate-a-line-chart-over-column-chart-using-highcharts  here i have already written my updated code

Comment: As I can see, Sebastian is trying to help resolve your issue. It's not necessary to duplicate work :)

Comment: Fus please help me in this question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299621/populate-dual-axes-line-and-column-charts-of-highcharts  Nobody can give me solutions.So please

Comment: Fus Thanks for you response, yes i have already getting this answers.