# HighCharts issues in Dual axes, line and column charts

Tags: mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to generate Dual axes, line and column charts of highcharts .I have tried stackoverflows sugesstions but i couldn't find proper solution.I have the data formatted properly but yet the chart is not generate shows  blank.I want this type of [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/dwyNz/8/ .In spline line I want to show 'bsp values' and in column I want to show facilities_total. So below i show my code for this graph.I also pointed my error in index.php.

Here is my **Index.php**

```
     $(function () {
       $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Project faclityv Rating'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'testing'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: []
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
              //  format: '{value} Rs.',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Bsp Cost',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'facility rating',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                //format: '{value} out of 100',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Facility Rating',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' out of 100'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Bsp Cost',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'Rs.'
            }
        }]
    });

     $.getJSON("combochart.php", function(json) {

          options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];  /*error here: ReferenceError: options is not defined */
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
```

Here is my **combochart.php**

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,superfac_rating.faci_total 
 FROM projects_detail LEFT OUTER JOIN superfac_rating 
 ON projects_detail.project_id= superfac_rating.project_id ");

    $category = array();
    $category['name'] = 'Project';
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $category['data'][] = $row1['Project_name'];
    $series1['data'][] = $row1['faci_total'];
   }

   $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,superfac_rating.faci_total 
   FROM projects_detail LEFT OUTER JOIN superfac_rating 
   ON projects_detail.project_id= superfac_rating.project_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN cost ON gsuperfac_rating.project_id=cost.project_id  ");

   $series1 = array();
   $series1['name'] = 'Project Name';
   $series2 = array();
   $series2['name'] = 'BSP VALUES';

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
   $series1['data'][] = $row2['faci_total'];
    $series2['data'][] = $row2['bsp'];
    }
     $result = array();
         array_push($result,$category);
         array_push($result,$series1);
         array_push($result,$series1);
          array_push($result,$series2);
       print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I think i have problem in json code thats why i can't fetch data  for graph.i checked in my console no errors.but i debug this code and json result shows me(json o/p writes in jsfiddle) but graph not appear in browser. i am explained in jsfiddle[link] jsfiddle.net/sunman/rDYvt/9 please check this. give me solution where i am wrong.So please help me and resolve my query.

Comment: Have you tried setting static data to the yAxis instead of fetching it from JSON? Just to check if the error is in parsing that data or chart configuration. You should know that it's likely Highcharts won't render anything if it finds a null, NaN (or that kind of data) in your data set. Please console.log your JSON parsing and post it here

Comment: @lascort error comes ReferenceError: options is not defined
options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];   So how it will be

Comment: @lascort Yes I have tested with static data but it runs fine But when i fetching data from json then  error comes ReferenceError: options is not defined
options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];   So how it will be rectify.

Comment: get your code in JSFiddle so we can have a better look at it

Comment: @lascort [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/rDYvt/9/ please check here i have mentioned all my code.My json output comes but graph not display on my browser

Comment: post your JSON as well...

Comment: @lascort i can't understand .please see me with a example of my code.Here json result shows the proper data.but why my graph not generate.please tell me how it is possible.I already faced this problem from last 7 days but i have no proper solution for this problem.As request to you please help me.

Comment: @lascort please check [link]http://jsfiddle.net/rDYvt/10/ .cocsole shows  [{"name":"Project","data":["Green View","Grand","Arete","Canary Greens","Terra","Beethovens","Ninex City","South Park","Callidora","Lotus","Coban","NCR Green","Kocoon","Estella","NCR One"]},{"name":"Facilities Rating","data":[45,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55]},{"name":"BSP VALUES","data":[97500,55745,16400,98700,38600,12090,94700,11400,12450,89500,86725,88335,54200,18200,30400]}]  So request to you where is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your **$.getJSON("combochart.php", function(json)** you need to setData like this

```
     theChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(json[0]['data']); 
     theChart.series[0].setData(json[1]['data'], false);
     theChart.series[1].setData(json[2]['data'], true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.now it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's working now...

Paste this in a JSFiddle to see it working...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var json= '[{"name":"Project","data":["Green View","Grand","Arete","Canary Greens","Terra","Beethovens","Ninex City","South Park","Callidora","Lotus","Coban","NCR Green","Kocoon","Estella","NCR One"]},{"name":"Facilities Rating","data":[45,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55]},{"name":"BSP VALUES","data":[97500,55745,16400,98700,38600,12090,94700,11400,12450,89500,86725,88335,54200,18200,30400]}]'

        var jsobj = JSON.parse(json)
        var firstSeriesData = [];
        var secondSeriesData = [];
        jsobj[1].data.forEach(function(seriesOneData){
            firstSeriesData.push(seriesOneData);  
        })

        jsobj[2].data.forEach(function(seriesTwoData){
            secondSeriesData.push(seriesTwoData);
        })

        $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy',
            type: 'column',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 50
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Top 12 Projects Facilities Rating and BSP Costs ',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: jsobj[0].data
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Facilities Rating'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width:1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions:{
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color:'white'
                }
            }
       },
       legend: {
           layout: 'vertical',
           align: 'right',
           verticalAlign: 'top',
           borderWidth: 0,
           x: -10,
           y:110
       },
       series: [ {
           name:'Facilities Rating',
           data:firstSeriesData, 
           id:'dataseries' 
       },{
           name:'BSP',
           type:'spline',
           data:secondSeriesData
        }]
    })
});
```

A couple comments.. your JSON had an unidentified character in it. This is what I got from pasting your JSON string.

[image]

Notice that red dot in the middle of the JSON.

Also, make sure you load highcharts modules in this order...

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

And lastly, you have two series in there, but one of them has values below 100 and the other one has values over 100k. So the first series is not gonna show as it almost 0 compared to the second. You'll have to do something about that.

Comment: Thanking you.now your code runs fine.but one thing i did not marked for compare values between two series.Whatever you write on last for compare values between two series its absolutely correct.For this problem whatis the solution.So I request to you please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

In your function `$.getJSON("combochart.php", function(json)` you need to explicitly define what `options` you want. You are also not acutally setting any data. I am assuming that `json[0]['data']` is a list of categories like `['Cat1', 'Cat2',...]` and that `json[1]` and `json[2]` contain the data like `[val1, val2, ...]`. If so you need to do something like this:

```
 $.getJSON("combochart.php", function(json) {
      var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
      theChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(json[0]['data']);  /*error here: ReferenceError: options is not defined */
        theChart.series[0].setData(json[1]);
        theChart.series[1].setData(json[2]);

        //chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
});
```

Comment: On the above code I modified but again Shows Error:   TypeError: theChart.xAxis.setCategories is not a function  .so how it is possible

Comment: Still now not working with this code.so tell me what is other way

Comment: Can you put up what code you have on a jsFiddle? What errors are you getting now?

Comment: Thanks for your response.i checked in my console no errors.but i debug this code and json result shows me(json o/p writes in jsfiddle) but graph not appear in browser. i am explained in jsfiddle [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/rDYvt/9/  please check this. give me solution where i am wrong

Comment: Looking at that code (it fails for the combochart.php which is expected as it is not on that site) I see you are invoking export.js twice - once before your highcharts.js and once after. This is causing highcharts undefined errors you are seeing. Make sure you reference highcharts.js then exporting.js afterwards and only once. In essence you call your framework, library library.dependencies in order of reference.

Comment: Thank you for such suggestion.yes it is absolutely right.